# Listview using LazyAdapter and Thread using ProgressDialog

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm trying to implement a thread that shows a progressdialog before loading the listview which is a source xml, but doing so in a thread is an error warning that the function Lazy Adapter need to have a thread, too, would like some suggestions for this problem, thanks.

Main:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.main);

    handler = new Handler();
    new Thread(){            
         public void run() {
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading...");                      
                }
            });             
             ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
                String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
                Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);


                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                    map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                    map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
                    map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
                    map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    songsList.add(map);
                }

                lista=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

                adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList); // ERROR APPEARS HERE 
                lista.setAdapter(adapter);


            progressDialog.cancel();
        }
     }.start();
}
```

LazyAdapter.java

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}
```

Comment: is that an error or warning? wat do u mean by "error warning"?

Comment: The error is: The constructor LazyAdapter(new Runnable(){}, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to fix your code can you try this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.main);

handler = new Handler();
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading...");
new Thread(){            
     public void run() {

         ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);


            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
                map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
                map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                songsList.add(map);
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    lista=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

                    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList); // ERROR APPEARS HERE 
                    lista.setAdapter(adapter);


                    progressDialog.cancel();
                }
            });             

        }
     }.start();
}
```

Comment: After change the error is: java.lang.ClassCastException: br.com.farmacia.OfertasActivity$1$1 cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Comment: Try class_activity_name.this instead of "this" in adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList) in this line.

Comment: Ok, it's working, but I would like progressDialog appear when you open the activity of at least 2 seconds before loading the list, is it possible?

Comment: No while creating activity I think it is not possible but why you need. if you want to display it for two second solution is there but I dont think it needed you activity takes time while creating so you cannot do it while activity creation you can do but till then your listview will appear so you no need to do it. If you want then i am having an idea but it is a little complecated.

Answer (score 0):

UI interface only in the main thread

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading...");  in child thread
```

so have this proplem